# How do you convert thread.sleep to javax.swing.timer?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, timer

Is there a way to easily convert thread.sleep to javax.swing.timer?

The reason why I would need to do this, is to stop the user-interface from freezing when you press a button, so that you can implement a pause button.

Code Example:

```
btnStartTiming.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                try{
                         inputA = Double.parseDouble(txtEnterHowLong.getText()); //Changes double to string and receives input from user
                        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){                        
                        }

            while (counter <= inputA){
                    txtCounter.setText(counter + ""); 
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();   
                    }
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    counter++;
                    }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the javax.swing.timer into this code.

Comment: Tutorials are waiting.

Comment: Replace the entire `while` loop.  Each iteration of the `while` loop would be mapped into the `actionPerformed` method of the registered `ActionListener` of the `java.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put the `java.swing.Timer` in your constructor. You can use the button to  `.start()` the timer.
- Also instead of the `while`, you can add an if statement in the timer code check when to `.stop()`

Something like this

```
int delay = 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, null);

public Constructor(){
    timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (counter >= inputA) {
                timer.stop();
            } else {

                // do something
            }
        }
    });
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some tips:

- Take a look to [How to use Swing
  Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
  trail and come back with concrete problems. Describe what are you trying to accomplish and your work so far, show your attempts to solve the problem and make an answerable question.
- Don't use [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)
  to listen when a button is pressed. Use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)
  instead. Take a look to [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio 
  Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) trail.